# R quantmod chartSeries: Add multiple TA overlay to single chart

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm trying to add multiple TA's to my main chartSeries chart, and they all add below instead of overlaying each other. Is it possible to add multiple TA overlays?

```
chartSeries(GE, theme="white",
TA="addTA(GE1);addTA(GE2);addTA(GE3)")
```

I've tried with the variables below;

on=1 and
overlay=TRUE

I'm looking for all the TA's to be in a single chart.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `on=1` is what you need. I'm having trouble getting the TA="" to work, with the data I had to hand, but this did work:

```
chartSeries(x,TA=NULL);addTA(EMA(x$Close),on=1)
```

(The `TA=NULL` is to remove the volume chart.)

Or, use `newTA` to define your TA with all the desired parameters in advance, and then the `TA` argument does accept it:

```
myEMA = newTA(EMA, Cl, on=1, col=7)
chartSeries(x, TA="myEMA()")
```

(See `?newTA`, which is where I stole that first line from!)

Comment: chartSeries(GE, theme="white"); addTA(GE1,on=1);addTA(GE2,on=1);addTA(GE3,on=1)